# Annotate ggplot bar chart Error: Unused arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I am trying to annotate standard messages on the bar charts that I am creating through a function. The following is the code:

```
    hashbar <- function(x) {
    suppressWarnings(library(stringr))
    hash <- "#[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}"
    hashtg <- str_extract_all(x$text, hash)
    hashtg <- as.data.frame(unlist(hashtg))
    hashtg <- as.data.frame(sort(table(hashtg), decreasing = TRUE)[1:15])
    names(hashtg)[1] <- "Freq"  
    hashtg$hashtag <- rownames(hashtg)
    rownames(hashtg) <- NULL
    suppressWarnings(library(ggplot2))
    suppressWarnings(library(RColorBrewer))
    p <- ggplot(hashtg, aes(x=reorder(hashtag, Freq), y = Freq, fill = hashtag)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
            geom_bar(width = 0.4) + xlab("Hashtags Used") + ylab("Number of responses") + 
            geom_text(aes(label=Freq), hjust = 1, colour = "white" ) + 
            ggtitle("Analysis of Most Frequently Used Hashtags") + 
            theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.2), lineheight = 1, face = "bold")) +
            theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black")) +
            theme(axis.title = element_text(size=12, face = "bold")) + 
            theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95")) +        
            theme(legend.position = "none") +
            coord_flip() 
    p + annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = "This is a test", hjust = 1.1, vjust = -0.5)
    p
}
```

The data:

```
        structure(list(text = c("_ShaneMacD: Great tour between the two sides. Shame the Kiwis have to go so the Aussies can come over. #ENGvNZ", 
   "- Kailua Kona, Hawaii : #travel #tour #trip #vacation #holiday #adventure #place #destinations #outd http://t.co/MocA1VMmup", 
   "- Kailua Kona, Hawaii : #travel #tour #trip #vacation #holiday #adventure #place #destinations #outd http://t.co/QHf2neoDHn", 
   "- Kailua Kona, Hawaii : #travel #tour #trip #vacation #holiday #adventure #place #destinations #outd http://t.co/vTbrdqw4tq", 
   "-----&gt; http://t.co/5cE07Ey3JM Some amazing places of India #IncredibleIndia #tourism #travel #traveltips #PlacesILove   http://t.co/p3fnVJhNGS", 
   "----&gt; http://t.co/2vWtTWdBD6 Before dying make sure to visit these places buddies #travel #tourism #Backpacking #trip #tourists #cool"
   ), inreply = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), source = c("IFTTT", "Pinterest", 
   "Pinterest", "Pinterest", "TwitterWebClient", "TwitterWebClient"
   ), tweet_time = c("24/06/15 2:41", "30/06/15 11:54", "30/06/15 11:54", 
   "30/06/15 11:54", "15/06/15 15:45", "25/06/15 12:08"), screen_name = c("izenkast", 
   "myvacationtour", "myvacationtour", "myvacationtour", "Alchetron", 
   "Alchetron"), followers = c(7223L, 489L, 489L, 489L, 60909L, 
   61862L), friends = c(759L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 42989L, 49767L), favorites = c(3L, 
   0L, 0L, 0L, 72L, 88L), statuses = c(16761L, 4069L, 4065L, 4066L, 
   301L, 343L), membersince = c("04/01/15 0:23", "26/04/12 10:11", 
   "26/04/12 10:11", "26/04/12 10:11", "08/11/13 21:09", "08/11/13 21:09"
   ), timezone = c("Chennai", "ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,380015", 
   "ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,380015", "ahmedabad,Gujarat,India,380015", 
   "Mumbai, Maharashtra", "Mumbai, Maharashtra"), tweet_date = c("24/06/15", 
   "30/06/15", "30/06/15", "30/06/15", "15/06/15", "25/06/15"), 
   twit_time = c("24/06/15 2:41", "30/06/15 11:54", "30/06/15 11:54", 
   "30/06/15 11:54", "15/06/15 15:45", "25/06/15 12:08"), rtt = c("T", 
   "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"), state = c("TN", "Guj", "Guj", "Guj", 
   "Mah", "Mah"), zone = c("South", "West", "West", "West", 
   "West", "West")), .Names = c("text", "inreply", "source", 
   "tweet_time", "screen_name", "followers", "friends", "favorites", 
   "statuses", "membersince", "timezone", "tweet_date", "twit_time", 
   "rtt", "state", "zone"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want a standard text message to be annotated to the right hand side bottom of the chart irrespective of x-axis range. I used Inf (an example shown in the ggplot cookbook), the following error is returned.

```
Error in annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = "This is a test",  : 
unused arguments (x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = "This is a test", hjust = 1.1, vjust = -0.5)
```

The session info:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] chron_2.3-45       gridExtra_0.9.1    topicmodels_0.2-2  lda_1.3.2            sna_2.3-2         
[6] igraph_0.7.1       slam_0.1-32        wordcloud_2.5      tm_0.6-1           NLP_0.1-7         
[11] repmis_0.4.4       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 ggplot2_1.0.1      stringr_1.0.0      shinyapps_0.4.1.4 
[16] downloader_0.4     quantmod_0.4-5     TTR_0.23-0         xts_0.9-7          zoo_1.7-12        
[21] mapproj_1.2-2      maps_2.3-9         shiny_0.12.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] modeltools_0.2-21 reshape2_1.4.1    lattice_0.20-31   colorspace_1.2-6     stats4_3.2.0     
[6] htmltools_0.2.6   SnowballC_0.5.1   R.oo_1.19.0       R.utils_2.1.0       R.cache_0.10.0   
[11] plyr_1.8.2        munsell_0.4.2     gtable_0.1.2      R.methodsS3_1.7.0 labeling_0.3     
[16] httpuv_1.3.2      parallel_3.2.0    proto_0.3-10      Rcpp_0.11.6       xtable_1.7-4     
[21] scales_0.2.4      jsonlite_0.9.16   mime_0.3          digest_0.6.8      stringi_0.4-1    
[26] RJSONIO_1.3-0     tools_3.2.0       bitops_1.0-6      magrittr_1.5      RCurl_1.95-4.7   
[31] MASS_7.3-40       data.table_1.9.4  httr_0.6.1        rstudioapi_0.3.1  R6_2.0.1         
[36] rstudio_0.98.1103
```

Comment: Have you tested if your code works outside the function?  Does the example code based on the `faithful` dataset you are working off of run without error for you?

Comment: I have tested the outside the function too...It doesn't work.  Though I have not tried the faithful dataset.  I am working with the dataset that i have provided.  The actual dataset I am working with has around 400000 lines...hence don't know if the problem is due to the dataset that I am using.  Will try using the code with a different dataset.

Comment: I tried the following code:     library(ggplot2)
 library(grid)

 qplot(1:10, rnorm(10)) +
   annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = "PROOF ONLY",
            hjust=1.1, vjust=-1.1, col="white", cex=6,
            fontface = "bold", alpha = 0.8) I am getting the same error

Comment: I am using ggplot2 _1.0.1...updated the session info now.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Package NLP has an `annotate` function that will mask `ggplot2::annotate` when you load NLP after ggplot2.  You get a message about this maskingwhen you load package `NLP`.

Comment: Thank you aosmith.  I tried unloading NLP...got a message it is required by package tm...tried unloading tm....it is required by topicmodels...and on and on...couldn't unload any of the packages...as each one is required in some other function. Don't know how to proceed...apart from annotating, i have to include a watermark too.

Comment: You can refer to the ggplot2 version of `annotate` in your code via `ggplot2::annotate("text",...)`.

Comment: Many thanks aosmith...this works!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package *NLP* also has an `annotate` function, and because you loaded that after *ggplot2*, `NLP::annotate` ended up masking `ggplot2::annotate`.  You get a warning message about masking when you load *NLP* after *ggplot2*:

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(NLP)
```

> Attaching package: ‘NLP’
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
>
> ```
> annotate
> ```

You can always explicitly use a function from a specific package using the package name and two colons.  In your case, use `ggplot2::annotate` instead of `annotate` to avoid this problem if the work in your current session involves package *NLP* and you don't want to go back and switch the order of package loading.